# Join two sql queries

Tags: sql, database, join

I have two SQL queries, where the first one is:

```
select Activity, SUM(Amount) as "Total Amount 2009"
from Activities, Incomes
where Activities.UnitName = ? AND
      Incomes.ActivityId = Activities.ActivityID
GROUP BY Activity
ORDER BY Activity;
```

and the second one is:

```
select Activity, SUM(Amount) as "Total Amount 2008"
from Activities, Incomes2008
where Activities.UnitName = ? AND
      Incomes2008.ActivityId = Activities.ActivityID
GROUP BY Activity
ORDER BY Activity;
```

(Dont mind the '?', they represent a parameter in birt).
What i want to achieve is the following:
I want an SQL query that returns the same as the first query, but with an additional (third) column which looks exactly like "Total Amount 2008" (from the 2nd query).

Comment: Join is a vague term.  Do you mean "outer join" or "inner join"?  What happens to activities that don't match between the two queries?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Some DBMSs support the `FROM (SELECT ...) AS alias_name` syntax.

Think of your two original queries as temporary tables. You can query them like so:

```
SELECT t1.Activity, t1."Total Amount 2009", t2."Total Amount 2008"
FROM (query1) as t1, (query2) as t2
WHERE t1.Activity = t2.Activity
```

Comment: the problem is though, that if one activity is zero, that activity will not be displayed. possbile to fix that with this elegant solution?

Comment: if the Activity were (null) instead of 0, it would be a piece of cake with a left outer join. But in this case it is rather difficult I'm afraid...

Comment: Maybe you could union this query with a special case for a zero on the left and one for a zero on the right.

Comment: Does Mysql support this?

Comment: @frazras Yes, it does.

Answer (score 21):

```
SELECT Activity, arat.Amount "Total Amount 2008", abull.Amount AS "Total Amount 2009"
FROM
  Activities a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (
  SELECT ActivityId, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
  FROM Incomes ibull
  GROUP BY
    ibull.ActivityId
  ) abull
ON abull.ActivityId = a.ActivityID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (
  SELECT ActivityId, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
  FROM Incomes2008 irat
  GROUP BY
    irat.ActivityId
  ) arat
ON arat.ActivityId = a.ActivityID
WHERE a.UnitName = ?
ORDER BY Activity
```

Comment: The statement compiles but the computed sums are way to large

Comment: Sorry, didn't get what you want on the first time. See updated post.

Answer (score 13):

I would just use a [Union](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)

In your second query add the extra column name and add a `''` in all the corresponding locations in the other queries

Example

```
//reverse order to get the column names
select top 10 personId, '' from Telephone//No Column name assigned 
Union 
select top 10 personId, loanId from loan
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's what worked for me:

```
select visits, activations, simulations, simulations/activations
   as sims_per_visit, activations/visits*100
   as adoption_rate, simulations/activations*100
   as completion_rate, duration/60
   as minutes, m1 as month, Wk1 as week, Yr1 as year 

from
(
    (select count(*) as visits, year(stamp) as Yr1, week(stamp) as Wk1, month(stamp)
    as m1 from sessions group by week(stamp), year(stamp)) as t3

    join

    (select count(*) as activations, year(stamp) as Yr2, week(stamp) as Wk2,
    month(stamp) as m2 from sessions where activated='1' group by week(stamp),
    year(stamp)) as t4

    join

    (select count(*) as simulations, year(stamp) as Yr3 , week(stamp) as Wk3,
    month(stamp) as m3 from sessions where simulations>'0' group by week(stamp),
    year(stamp)) as t5

    join

    (select avg(duration) as duration, year(stamp) as Yr4 , week(stamp) as Wk4,
    month(stamp) as m4 from sessions where activated='1' group by week(stamp),
    year(stamp)) as t6
)
where Yr1=Yr2 and Wk1=Wk2 and Wk1=Wk3 and Yr1=Yr3 and Yr1=Yr4 and Wk1=Wk4
```

I used joins, not unions (I needed different columns for each query, a join puts it all in the same column) and I dropped the quotation marks (compared to what Liam was doing) because they were giving me errors.

Thanks! I couldn't have pulled that off without this page!
PS: Sorry I don't know how you're getting your statements formatted with colors. etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can use CTE also like below.

```
With cte as
(select Activity, SUM(Amount) as "Total Amount 2009"
   from Activities, Incomes
  where Activities.UnitName = ? AND
        Incomes.ActivityId = Activities.ActivityID
  GROUP BY Activity
),
cte1 as 
(select Activity, SUM(Amount) as "Total Amount 2008"
   from Activities, Incomes2008
  where Activities.UnitName = ? AND
        Incomes2008.ActivityId = Activities.ActivityID
  GROUP BY Activity
)
Select cte.Activity, cte.[Total Amount 2009] ,cte1.[Total Amount 2008]      
  from cte join cte1 ON cte.ActivityId = cte1.ActivityID
 WHERE a.UnitName = ?
 ORDER BY cte.Activity
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select Activity, SUM(Incomes.Amount) as "Total Amount 2009", SUM(Incomes2008.Amount) 
as "Total Amount 2008" from
Activities, Incomes, Incomes2008
where Activities.UnitName = ?  AND
Incomes.ActivityId = Activities.ActivityID  AND
Incomes2008.ActivityId = Activities.ActivityID GROUP BY
Activity ORDER BY Activity;
```

Basically you have to JOIN Incomes2008 table with the output of your first query.

Comment: Because you have used inner joins, the result will not contain rows with no income in 2008 or no income in 2009 (ie not having a row in the income table)

Comment: My initial attempt looked something like this. didnt work though

Answer (score 1):

If you assume that values exist for all activities in both years then just do an inner join as follows

```
 select act.activity, t1.amount as "Total 2009", t2.amount as "Total 2008"
from Activities as act,
    (select activityid,  SUM(Amount) as amount
    from Activities, Incomes
    where Activities.UnitName = ? AND
          Incomes.ActivityId = Activities.ActivityID
    GROUP BY Activityid) as t1,
    (select activityid, SUM(Amount) as amount
    from Activities, Incomes2008
    where Activities.UnitName = ? AND
          Incomes2008.ActivityId = Activities.ActivityID
    GROUP BY Activityid) as t2
    WHERE t1.activityid= t2.activityid
    AND act.activityId = t1.activityId
    ORDER BY act.activity
```

If you can't assume this, then look at doing an outer join

Comment: Sorry there may have been an extra semicolon running around.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps not the most elegant way to solve this

```
select  Activity, 
        SUM(Amount) as "Total_Amount",
        2009 AS INCOME_YEAR
from    Activities, Incomes
where Activities.UnitName = ? AND
      Incomes.ActivityId = Activities.ActivityID
GROUP BY Activity
ORDER BY Activity;

UNION

select  Activity, 
        SUM(Amount) as "Total_Amount",
        2008 AS INCOME_YEAR
from Activities, Incomes2008
where Activities.UnitName = ? AND
      Incomes2008.ActivityId = Activities.ActivityID
GROUP BY Activity
ORDER BY Activity;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy when you see the solution.

```
With name1 as (your_query_here),
name2 as (your_second_query_here)
select * from name1 JOIN name2.attribute=name1.attribute;
```

**Attribute** is on the common values that two SQL queries possess.