# FQL Multi query multiple SELECT statements in the IN clause

Tags: facebook, select, facebook-fql

I'm using [FQL multiquery](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.multiquery/) and I just need something like their `query2` example, except I need to select the uids from two different queries.

In other words they have:

```
"query2":"SELECT name, url, pic FROM profile WHERE id IN (SELECT uid FROM #query1)"
```

I'd want to have something like:

```
"query3":"SELECT name, url, pic FROM profile WHERE id IN (SELECT uid FROM #query1, SELECT uid FROM #query2)"
```

But clearly `(SELECT uid FROM #query1, SELECT uid FROM #query2)` is not the right syntax to use here as Facebook returns an error. What's the right syntax? I tried Googling but it's kind of hard to Google for this.

And yes, I know I could just add a `query4` and split the `(SELECT uid FROM #query1, SELECT uid FROM #query2)` between `query3` and `query4`, but this feels more elegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just making another query (`query4`) for the second `SELECT uid FROM #query2`, as it looks like Facebook doesn't support exactly what I initially wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can join both query 1 and query 2 so you get only one table, i think its the best way to achieve what you are trying to do.

```
SELECT xxx FROM xxx WHERE xxx IN(
    SELECT q1.uid,q2.uid
    FROM (query1) as q1, (query2) as q2
    WHERE "joining clause"
)
```

source:
[Join two sql queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564997/join-two-sql-queries)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work (just tried), because Facebook only allows one table in the `FROM` part (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/, Query part).