# JOIN two queries in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join

I have the simple query:

```
SELECT t1.JOB_ID 
FROM 
(
  select 1 as JOB_ID 
  from JOBS2
) as t1 
INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT 2 AS JOB_ID 
   from JOBS
) as t2 ON t1.JOB_ID = t2.JOB_ID;
```

and I have this error:

> Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

is it because of the syntax? or it's another problem?

Comment: You know that your query makes no sense?

Comment: I don't know enough about oracle to say why you're getting that error, but your query makes no sense.  It's essentially saying "give me all the 1's where the 1 equals 2."  What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL join subquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18718444/sql-join-subquery)

Comment: Look at the proposed duplicate.  The first comment says to remove the AS keywords.  I tried that on sql fiddle and it parsed correctly (didn't run because I didn't have a jobs table).

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9a9e5/6 wow so weird you can use `AS` on the fieldname but not in the table.

Comment: I have a really long query, I don't care about the sens of the query, I just simplified till maximum to see the mistake, cause in sintaxis I based everything in examples like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564997/join-two-sql-queries

But I don't care the result, I just want it tu run!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove AS before subqueries names

```
SELECT t1.JOB_ID 
FROM 
(
  select 1 as JOB_ID 
  from JOBS2
) t1 
INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT 2 AS JOB_ID 
   from JOBS
) t2 ON t1.JOB_ID = t2.JOB_ID;
```