# Perform join on joined queries with N number of rows per type

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is a follow-up question to [stackexchange]: [Perform join on joined queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49809144/perform-join-on-joined-queries). Please read this first.

The initial question on how to transpose rows based on a certain type has been answered, but now I also need this extend to a potential N number of rows.

Example table for this case:

```
+------+--------------+--------------+--------+----------+
| type | information1 | information2 | Notes  | uniqueID |
+------+--------------+--------------+--------+----------+
| IN   | infoA        | anotherinfo1 | NotesA | SN1      |
+------+--------------+--------------+--------+----------+
| IN   | infoB        | anotherinfo2 | NotesB | SN1      |
+------+--------------+--------------+--------+----------+
| OUT  | infoC        | anotherinto3 | NotesC | SN2      |
+------+--------------+--------------+--------+----------+
| OUT  | infoD        | anotherinto4 | NotesD | SN2      |
+------+--------------+--------------+--------+----------+
```

Basically I think I would need a loop over each 'IN' and 'OUT' type. In order to transpose the N IN and OUT to columns and then later join with another table. No idea how to do this.

Table (B) in related SO ticket shows the target output and would need to extend by N columns for Info N etc.

Comment: use `Dynamic SQL`

Comment: @Squirrel: I will try to lean this but so far I have no experience with this level of SQL. Would you have any hints?

Comment: try http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: Thanks will check that one.