# Top 1 in group by clause in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm creating a trading platform and I need from a table to bring the following data:

```
date, open price, close price, highest price, lowest price, volume, value of volume.
```

I created this query :

```
Select 
    min(Price) as Low,
    max(price) as High,
    sum(Quantity) as Volume,
    sum(Price) as Value,
    dateadd(DAY, 0, datediff(day, 0, CreatedOn)) as Date,
    CompanyIdentifier 
from 
    Transactions 
group by 
    dateadd(DAY, 0, datediff(day, 0, CreatedOn)), CompanyIdentifier
```

What is this query is doing is for a certain company (identified by `CompanyIdentifier`) on a certain day (Date) brings the lowest price,highest price,volume and value of volume.What I cannot add in this query is the open price and the close price for that company in that day.Basically the top 1 price with the data ordered ascending by date.What I tried and it seems to do the trick is the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (select Quantity, PRICE, CompanyIdentifier, 
             dateadd(DAY,0, datediff(day,0, CreatedOn)) AS U, 
             ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by CompanyIdentifier, dateadd(DAY,0, datediff(day,0, CreatedOn)) order by CREATEDON) AS 'COUN' 
      from Transactions
     ) AS AL 
where COUN = 1
```

But these are 2 separate queries and I want only one query.I also tried to add:

```
FIRST_VALUE(Price) over (order by price) as first
```

in the first query but I received the error that the function in not in a group by clause,I added the function the the group by query and I receive the following error :

> Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.

So,how could I add those two columns in the first query ?

Comment: Add some sample data with your expected output from them.

Comment: This is what I am receiving now : https://imgur.com/a/u4VSFKZ
And I want beside those columns to add 2 more columns:starting price and closing price.Basically  to bring the first price and last price,for each company represented by CompanyIdentifier in each date (represented by date)

Comment: You don't have OPEN or CLOSE prices based on the image you posted because the time component is consistently set to 00:00. Nor is there a "first" or "last" row in a table. By definition, rows have no particular order in a table and certainly not one you can rely on.

Comment: Yes,the time component is set to 00:00 in order to be able to group the data by day.But in the database the time component also has hours,minutes and seconds.I know there is no order in a table by definition,but based on the data field I can order them in asc order or desc and select top 1.The issue is that the data is grouped and I cannot use top 1 function to get the first or last price in  a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to use window functions and `select distinct`:

```
select distinct t.CompanyIdentifier, v.createdDate,
       min(Price) over (partition by t.CompanyIdentifier, v.createdDate) as Low,
       max(price) over (partition by t.CompanyIdentifier, v.createdDate) as High,
       sum(Quantity) over (partition by t.CompanyIdentifier, v.createdDate) as Volume,
       sum(Price) over (partition by t.CompanyIdentifier, v.createdDate) as Value,
       first_value(Price) over (partition by t.CompanyIdentifier, v.createdDate order by CreatedOn asc) as first_price,   
       first_value(Price) over (partition by t.CompanyIdentifier, v.createdDate order by CreatedOn desc) as last_price   
from Transactions t cross apply
     (values (convert(date, CreatedOn))) v(createdDate)
```

This is needed because SQL Server offers `first_value()` as a window function, but nothing similar as an aggregation function.

A more traditional approach uses conditional aggration:

```
Select t.CompanyIdentifier, t.createdDate,
       min(Price) as Low, max(price) as High,
       sum(Quantity) as Volume, sum(Price) as Value,
       min(case when seqnum_asc = 1 then price end) as first_price,
       min(case when seqnum_desc = 1 then price end) as last_price
from (select t.*,
             createdDate,
             row_number() over (partition by CompanyIdentifier, createdDate order by CreatedOn) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by CompanyIdentifier, createdDate order by CreatedOn desc) as seqnum_desc
      from Transactions t cross apply
           (values (convert(date, CreatedOn))) v(createdDate)
     ) t
group by t.CompanyIdentifier, v.createdDate;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I tried both queries.The first one returned a group by error:
Column 'Transactions.Price' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
The second one works but the first_price and last_price are the same.I added a screenshot from the database here: https://imgur.com/a/xyTfZN4
I tried to debug the second query,but frankly is rather advanced for me.If you could give me some insight it would be great :)

Comment: @WorkoutChannel . . . The first one should NOT have a `GROUP BY` (that is the point of `SELECT DISTINCT`).  The second needed a `DESC` on the sort.

Answer (score 0):

`FIRST_VALUE() OVER` is an analytic function and to my experience they don't mesh too well with a GROUP BY clause.

An easy workaround should be joining a subquery that uses analytic functions `FIRST_VALUE` into your table and for closing price `LAST_VALUE` could do the trick.

```
Select 
min(Price) as Low,
max(price) as High,
sum(Quantity) as Volume,
sum(Price) as Value,
dateadd(DAY, 0, datediff(day, 0, CreatedOn)) as Date,
analytic.first,
analytic.close
CompanyIdentifier 
from 
Transactions,
(SELECT CompanyIdentifier, FIRST_VALUE(price) OVER (CreatedOn) as first, LAST_VALUE(price) OVER (CreatedOn) as close) as analytic
where
Transactions.CompanyIdentifier = analytic.CompanyIdentifier 
group by 
dateadd(DAY, 0, datediff(day, 0, CreatedOn)), CompanyIdentifier,analytic.first,analytic.close
```

I hope it works for you, maybe some adjustment is needed for the query, as I used assumptions based on your example.

Comment: I did something similar,using the response from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564997/join-two-sql-queries
I joined 3 tables to form only one and selected only the columns that I needed,is kind of a messy solution but it seems to work.